# What does initialization for regressor?

Tags: deep-learning, face-detection, face-recognition

I'm a noob CV & deep-learning student

I've just started to read a Paper which is about better face detection tech

I'll bring a whole paragraph which I want to ask

we propose Improved Anchor Matching (IAM), which integrates anchor partition strategy and anchor-based data augmentation to better match anchors
and ground truth faces, and thus provides better initialization
for the regressor.

I roughly understands other sentences but I can't understand initialization for the regressor.

I've googled about that sentence but the only result is for initialization for regression or just regressor.

What does that means? TT

Comment: Can you provide us the link of the paper so that we can read and understand what actually regressor is?.

Comment: Thanks for your comment 
Here's the
[link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.10220v3.pdf)
There're many expression about initializaion for the regressor, the paragraph I
uploaded is at 1. Introduction's almost last part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that regressor is either a fully connected layer or a convolutional layer of the deep learning network layer. So mostly they are talking about the initialization of such layer.

Hope this will of your help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
After I heard your answer, I've got 2 more curious thing...
Could you answer my question?
1. In this paper, How Improved anchor matching can help initialization of regressor
2. What advantange does initializaion of regressor has?

Comment: @송석현 I will need some time to read and better understand the paper. Then only I can explain to you correctly. I suggest you mail the authors of the paper themselves for some of your queries. They will surely reply back to you with correct answers. I will help you with whatever I can. Thanks.

Comment: I'm really Thanks for your help.